# How do I change the speed of the slideshow in gThumb?

Tags: presentation, slideshow, gthumb

How do I change the speed of the slideshow in gThumb? Is there a properties menu I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Open gThumb preferences, under "*Viewer*" section you'll find the option.

[image]